# Best way to test for undefined variables / or NEXT siblings?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to test whether a particular div has another div after it, using `.next()` in jQuery. And if it does have another div after it, then I want to adjust some CSS.

I'm currently checking the CSS of the `.next()` div and if it's not `undefined` then proceeding with the CSS change but I don't think this is a very solid way of doing it.

```
var hasNext = $('.slide.active').next().attr('class'); // check the class of the "next" element

if(hasNext !== 'undefined'){
   // There is another slide! Add some arrows
   $('.portfolio .fp-controlArrow.fp-next').css('display','block');
}
```

Firstly this isn't working (despite the `console.log` showing `hasNext = undefined` the above if statement is passing.

Secondly I'm aware this is a clumsy way of doing things.

So how would you do this? Essentially:

```
if (slide with class `active` has a NEXT sibling){
    do this css
}
```

Comment: You missed typeof operator. `if(hasNext !== 'undefined'){` or it can be: `if(hasNext !== undefined){`

Answer (score 3):

Just check the length of the object returned by `.next()`, it will be `0` if there is no next sibling

```
var hasNext = $('.slide.active').next().length; // check the class of the "next" element

if (hasNext) {//check for truthyness
    // There is another slide! Add some arrows
    $('.portfolio .fp-controlArrow.fp-next').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: that's the best while using jQuery. +1

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
if (typeof hasNext !== 'undefined')
```